# How to migrate from TinyMCE 4 to TinyMCE 5 - Prestashop

Tags: tinymce, prestashop

A day ago my prestashop website, in the comment box of the blog started to display the following message:

[image: TinyMCE Migration]

And entering the post that explains how to migrate the version of TinyMCE , I do not understand very well how to perform these steps in my prestashop.

How can I update this?a

Comment: To be clear, did you add TinyMCE to a Prestashop site, or are you using TinyMCE as included in Prestashop's own application? If Prestashop is using TinyMCE in its application, then it is using a very old source for TinyMCE, that has since been shut down. Prestashop would have to update their application's code to resolve this issue.

Comment: @TinyLincoln The editor is integrated to prestashop. So updating the e-commerce would solve that problem, right?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a third-party module to make your blog it might be is including its own version of TinyMCE. You should try to dig in its code to understand that.

If this is not the case, the blog uses TinyMCE which is normally included in Prestashop core.
On said that, this second case is likely to be the one. Update the e-commerce unlikely will solve your problem. I honestly don't remember in which version they are with TinyMCE but doing an upgrade like that might break back-office editor forms so I don't think they are keen on that at the moment. They are doing a major rollover to Symfony, I am pretty sure this is their priority right now. As said in one comment, Prestashop's dev team has to solve the issue on their side.